# How can I change the language in my Launchpad account?

Tags: launchpad

I'm not able to change the language in my Launchpad account.

I've tried to do it from the edit language page after clicking on the little yellow pen.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That field, **Languages**, it is not for changing the site display language. That field is for your language preferences, which means:

> Your preferred languages are used to configure some Launchpad applications to work with the languages you know. Launchpad Translations allows you to translate a project into your preferred languages. Launchpad Answers allows you to ask and answer questions in your preferred languages. **Launchpad's default language is English, which is the only language for most Launchpad features.**

Source: https://launchpad.net/~thomas-produit/+editlanguages